# How do I fix a value error when using scipy.integrate odeint function?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I'm an engineering student and I'm trying to figure out how to use the odeint function from the scipy.integrate module (I've only ever used ode45 in MATLAB). I'm attempting to numerically solve a simple second order mass, spring, dashpot system. Below is the code I've written (specifically I'm using Jupyter Notebook and running the latest version of Python 3):

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
from matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

# Numerical solution to mx" + bx' + kx = f(t)

# Define state vector y and its derivative
def translational(x,t,m,b,k,f):
    y = [x[0], x[1]] # state vector
    ydot = [x[1], f -b/m*x[1] - k/m*x[0]] # derivative of state vector
    return ydot

# Parameters for the system
t = np.arange(0,10,0.01)
IC = [0, 0] #[x0 v0]
m = 10 # kg
b = 2 # N*s/m
k = 5 # N/m
f = 5*np.cos(10*t)
y = odeint(translational,IC,t,args=(m,b,k,f))
```

When I execute the code it returns the following error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-423018367c52> in <module>
     20 k = 5 # N/m
     21 f = 5*np.cos(10*t)
---> 22 y = odeint(translational,IC,t,args=(m,b,k,f))

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\odepack.py in odeint(func, y0, t, args, Dfun, col_deriv, full_output, ml, mu, rtol, atol, tcrit, h0, hmax, hmin, ixpr, mxstep, mxhnil, mxordn, mxords, printmessg, tfirst)
    239     t = copy(t)
    240     y0 = copy(y0)
--> 241     output = _odepack.odeint(func, y0, t, args, Dfun, col_deriv, ml, mu,
    242                              full_output, rtol, atol, tcrit, h0, hmax, hmin,
    243                              ixpr, mxstep, mxhnil, mxordn, mxords,

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

For the life of me I can't figure out what's wrong. Any help is much appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Is that all of the traceback?  I would focus on the type error.  I think some parameter is an array with more than one value, while it should be a scalar (or just one value).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`f` is an array of numbers, and therefore so is `f -b/m*x[1] - k/m*x[0]`, so the return value of your function `translational` is not correct.

Instead of attempting to precompute the values of `f`, what you should do is use the expression for the function in `translational`:

```
def translational(x,t,m,b,k):
    y = [x[0], x[1]] # state vector
    f = 5*np.cos(10*t)
    ydot = [x[1], f -b/m*x[1] - k/m*x[0]] # derivative of state vector
    return ydot
```

and remove `f` from the `args` parameter of the `odeint` function call.